# Are v8's optimizations deterministic? Extracting the sequence of JS functions executed by any given webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, v8

I am trying to reconstruct the exact sequence of executed Javascript functions (call graph) from log data gathered using the Tracing Profiler, particularly from the category "v8.cpu_profiler".

Unfortunately, the number of nodes (function definitions) and edges (function calls) I obtain fluctuates across runs even if I interact with the test Web application in exactly the same way.

Currently, I use Puppeteer to extract the trace and interact with the application:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    userDataDir: userDataFolder,
    args:[
        `--disable-extensions`,
        `--js-flags=--jitless --no-opt --predictable --no-concurrent-recompilation `] // disable chrome's optimizations
});

// Get the tab opened by default
let [page] = await browser.pages();

// Make sure to disable the cache
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

// create cdp session
const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();

await cdp.send('Tracing.start', {
    traceConfig: {
        recordMode: 'recordContinuously',
        includedCategories: ['disabled-by-default-v8.cpu_profiler'],
        excludedCategories: ['*']
    },
    transferMode: 'ReturnAsStream'
});

await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

// Go to the page
await Promise.race([
    page.goto(this.url, { waitUntil: ["load", "networkidle2"] }),
    page.waitForTimeout("body"),
]);

// Wait to make sure that the page is fully loaded
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

// dynamically interact with the webpage
await interact(page);
```

As you can see, I use the flags `--jitless --no-opt --predictable --no-concurrent-recompilation` to disable any source of non-determinism I know of, but it is still not enough. Why does this happen? Theoretically, the executed functions are exactly the same and the Tracing Profiler should be very precise.

Is it possible that v8 is still doing some optimizations under the hood and if yes, how can I disable them?

Is there any other way I can extract the exact sequence of executed functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 has a `--trace` flag, which gives an exact sequence of executed functions. Warning: it produces *lots* of output, because there are lots of function calls on typical websites.

The function call sequence is entirely deterministic. Internal optimizations have nothing to do with that, so there's no reason to turn them off. (Think about it: if optimization changed the order in which functions called each other, that would break applications. Whatever an engine does internally must not change the behavior that the developer of the website intended.)

The "Tracing Profiler" is a sample-based profiler, and as such non-deterministic by design (and there can't possibly be a flag to "turn that off"). It uses a ticker thread that samples the main thread every millisecond (or similar interval, I'm not sure about the exact value). What exactly the main thread is doing at this point will be different between different runs; it's only statistically meaningful (e.g. if a function takes X% of the overall time, it'll be represented on approximately X% of the sampling ticks).

Of course, JavaScript applications can have their own sources of non-determinism:
`if (Math.random() < 0.5) { foo(); } else { bar(); }` will create different call sequences on different runs. It's also conceivable that JavaScript reacts to mouse movements or other user interactions, which would be exceedingly difficult to replicate exactly.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. 
I think I misunderstand something tho. 

As far as I know, chromium should have two profilers:
1) The sampling profiler
2) The tracing profiler (chrome://tracing/).

From [v8 docs](https://v8.dev/docs/trace), it seems that my method above (that uses chrome's tracing profiler) should produce the same result I would obtain by using the flag ```--trace``` you mentioned. Isn't it?

Comment: You also said:
`The function call sequence is entirely deterministic. Internal optimizations have nothing to do with that, so there's no reason to turn them off.`

But I am sure that this is not the case since v8 can, for example, combine multiple functions into a single one (inlining) to speed up operations.
 This would modify the sequence of function calls v8 may output and I don't want it. Ideally, I would like to prevent this, making sure that v8 actually executes the exact 'raw' functions without applying any optimization that may result in any change done to the call graph.

Comment: @GianlucaDeStefano that appears to be a misunderstanding indeed, chrome://tracing is sampling-based. V8's `--trace` is not for performance measurements, and it's not used by chrome://tracing. -- Yes, you're right about inlining. `--noturbo-inlining` is the least intrusive way to turn that off.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Now I see why things do not work as I would like!
I have just two questions: 
1) I have done a quick test but I was unable to obtain any output while using --trace, and I can't find anything online on how to use it. At the moment, I am launching puppeteer in no sandbox mode and with the flag: `--js-flags=--logfile=v8.log,--trace`, but no file gets generated.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 2) Since you seem to know this stuff pretty well, can you please point me to some resource on how to use --trace and interpret the resulting logs?

Comment: I have noticed now that the results of '--trace' are printed into the stdout. 
Is there maybe any flag to write them directly to a file?

Comment: @GianlucaDeStefano `--trace` always prints to stdout. I suppose you could redirect stdout to a file. I don't think there's any documentation for this flag, the output should be self-explanatory (and the use cases are exceedingly niche).

Comment: I see, thanks. I can get the trace, but now I am thinking about how to use the data. An invocation of the function `Func1` is represented with the following notation: 'FUNC1+0(this=0x2e0e001c40ed <JSGlobalProxy>)'. That is nice, but if the invoked function is anonymous, I get the following log ~+0(this=0x2fe3001c40ed <JSGlobalProxy`>. As you can see, it is practically impossible to understand what function is invoked in this case (supposing multiple anonymous functions are present).  (1/2)

Comment: Ideally, I would like to get an exact reference to both the file and the lines containing the function's definition. Do you know any particular flag that may add information I could find useful? I have already looked at `--log-function-events` but that seem to have no scope information.

Comment: @GianlucaDeStefano There are no flags to customize the behavior of `--trace`. If you're willing to recompile Chrome for your project, you can adapt the output to your needs: e.g. in V8's src/runtime/runtime-test.cc around line 1333 in function Runtime_TraceEnter, change the last parameter to `JavaScriptFrame::PrintTop` from `false` to `true` to include `filename:linenumber` information in the printout.

Comment: Ok, I will take a shot at it in the coming days! Thanks for the invaluable tips!

Comment: Hey, sorry for resurrecting this old post but I had time just now to look into this more. 

The method suggested above works well, now I get the definition of the files where the functions are executed. 

For example, If in script.js I have two functions: `f1`,`f2` where`f2` calls 'f1' and it is itself invoked in the `index.html` file, I get the following output:
`

Comment: `1: ~+0 at file://<path>/2/index.html:7(this=0x2d6800283d0d <JSGlobalProxy>) {
   2:  ~f2+0 at file://<path>/2/scripts/script.js:1(this=0x2d6800283d0d <JSGlobalProxy>) {
   3:   ~f1+0 at file://<path>/2/scripts/script.js:1(this=0x2d6800283d0d <JSGlobalProxy>) {
   3:   } -> 0x2d68000023e1 <undefined>
   2:  } -> 0x2d68000023e1 <undefined>
   1: } -> 0x2d68000023e1 <undefined>
`


However, I still have 2 problems:

Comment: 1) As you can see, the 2 functions f1 and f2 share the same definition

  `file://<path>/2/scripts/script.js:1(this=0x2d6800283d0d <JSGlobalProxy>) `
  In particular, they share the same line number even if `f1` is defined at line 1 and `f2` at line 6.

2) F2 invokes the native function console.log; however, as you can see, it is not captured in the call stack. Is it possible to capture native calls as well ins some way?

Comment: @GianlucaDeStefano re 1, yeah, that does seem surprising, and I don't know what might be causing it. re 2, you'd have to craft a custom solution for each of them: either replace/wrap them on the JS side, or modify their respective implementations.

Comment: I see; I have mostly fixed (1). But of course, now I still have a problem to address. 
Essentially if some javascript code has been extracted from an html file the 'sharedfunctioninfo' object defining it will only refer to the code enclosed by the <script> tag. Therefore the rowCount and columnCount will contain wrong references as they will not take into account the HTML preceding the javascript code in the original .html file. I have looked a bit in the code, but it seems that from inside v8 there is no way to correct this (v8 only gets the already purified javascript). Am I wrong?